# What is wrong with the way I configured SSL in tomcat?

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat

Firstly, I'm trying to configure my java web project for school as HTTPS, so I'm trying to make a self signed certificate and import it to tomcat. My tomcat version is 9.0.591 and I'm using java 17.

I basically followed the documents in the official tomcat website.

I first created a keystore by running this exact command `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA`

[this is what I entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vXyA.png)

And then I simply added it to the tomcat server.xml file as such -

```
<Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

And I added this to the web.xml file -

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>DigitalLibrary</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Now I'm not gonna lie, I don't really know what the code in the web.xml file means so if you could explain that as well I'd appreciate it. All I know is that it makes the server automatically forward to https instead of http.

Lastly I ran the server, windows of course did not recognize the certificate so I downloaded the CER file straight from chrome and added it to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities through mmc.

When I tried running the server again the certificate still was not recognized. What did I do wrong that made windows not recognize it? It does obviously show up when I run the server but windows won't recognize it.... I have tried just putting up the keystore file in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities and it still didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not exactly a programming question. Perhaps this would be better posted to a sister site such as https://serverfault.com/  or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: By the way, rather than using a self-signed certificate, you might consider using [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to obtain a real certificate at no cost. I’ve no idea if that would help your problem or not.

Comment: Let's Encrypt will require the server to be reachable from the internet. Something like that is not necessary for test setups.

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri Test setups should be as close to the production setup as possible. You don't want to be testing different code.

Comment: All you did was create a keypair. The keytool happens to wrap the public key in a certificate but not of the kind you want. You need to generate a certificate using that keypair and with the DN equal to the domain name of your server.

Comment: @user207421: in the past using domain name _or_ address for _CommonName_ (which is not the whole DN) was correct, but today you need SAN instead. See my answer.

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri "Let's Encrypt will require the server to be reachable from the internet." Not true at all. You can use `dns-01` as validation method so you just need to prove control of the DNS, not control of the HTTP server (`http-01` method).

Answer (score 1):

Meta: this is not programming or development, and will probably get closed or moved. This doesn't fit as a comment but I consent to it being deleted or moved.

HTTPS certificates *must* contain the domain name you use to connect to the server, or the IP address if you use that instead which is rare on the internet but not uncommon in test environments, or optionally a wildcard *matching* the domain name.

For Chrome or Edge, you must add the [SubjectAlternativeName extension](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/keytool.html#supported-named-extensions) to the cert with the domain name(s) or IP address(es) of the server. See [the keytool documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/keytool.html). For other browsers you may do that or (at least for now) put *one* name or address of the server as 'Common Name' in Subject, which is what `keytool` describes inaccurately as "First and Last Name" (but note the confirmation shows it as CN, which is the correct abbreviation for Common Name).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was really dumb... I can't believe it took me so long to realize this...

Basically it only recognized the certificate when I used the IP in the url, I originally had "localhost" in there. That was the cause of the error in this case.

I also changed at some point to a certificate I made with openssl so it probably has to do with it.

Thank you to everyone that answered and I'm sorry for posting in the wrong site, I didn't even know there were other ones....

Comment: Don't use `https` URLs with IP addresses, this is the wrong move. Even if technically you can have certificates with IP addresses in them, this is the exception and not the norm. Let's Encrypt has a specific page explaining how to handle the "localhost" case, see https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/ (it is not specific to their CA).